# Removed unused references issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I used visual studios "Optimize references" function and pressed "remove all unused references"...bad idea. Now I am stuck with an issue that I don't know how to solve or even where to start. When i compile and run the web site the compiler breaks and says that a reference to WebMatrix.Data are missing(that was removed by the optimize-function)...I have re-added all references but it still won't work.

Compiler error is CS0234 and it's pointing to this file: c:\Users\joffa\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5008f7ae\9fa08eff\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.jwv3v7bj.0.cs    Row: 34

```
Rad 32:     #line default
Rad 33:     #line hidden
Rad 34:     using WebMatrix.Data;
Rad 35:     using WebMatrix.WebData;
Rad 36:     using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;
```

I have removed all temp-files i could found and added the references again but the error will not go away. Anyone have any clue how trace this?

Edit: It seems to be related to the account/membership that comes with asp.net mvc 4.5.

```
Rad 29:       #line 1 "C:\Users\joffa\path\Views\Home\Index.cshtml"
Rad 30:       
Rad 31:       
Rad 32:       #line default
Rad 33:       #line hidden
Rad 34:       using WebMatrix.Data;
Rad 35:       using WebMatrix.WebData;
Rad 36:       using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;
Rad 37:       using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet;
```

Where are these hidden lines in my files?

Comment: What is the exact path of the reference you added? (If you look at the reference's Properties)

Comment: For WebMatrix.Data it is
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\WebMatrix.Data.dll

Comment: Let me know if you need more info from the compiler...there is a lot more in the detailed output from the compiler.

Comment: Hmm that seems correct. And there's no yellow exclamation mark next to any of the references? Can you not diff in source control to see what might have gone wrong?

Comment: There is no exclamation mark...
What do you mean with "diff in source control", sound like something that i have not tried :)

Comment: You can try downloading a trial copy of ReSharper (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) It has worked magic for me before in dealing with references.  It also posses a very smart remove unused references function. I've never had it break something removing unused ref's.

Comment: I have ReSharper installed...but the damage is already done. Need a way to redo everything.

Comment: Go in the history of your source code control system and get the version before you made this change.

Comment: Did not have SC on. I solved by creating a new project and just copied all files and now it works...

Comment: I hope you've started using an SCC *now*...

Comment: Yes, now it's up and running :) Thanks